# REST API Service returns 500 error which is actually 404. Same working expected by calling IP Address of the service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service, iis-8.5, arr

We are facing a server related issue in one of our API Service application (ASP.NET WEB API 2). When we access the service by site domain name (api.xxx.com), the service returns an Internal server error (500). But If we accessing the same service by site IP address (11.111.11.111), Its returning proper result (404). This issue occurred only if the server trying to return 404.

1. https://api.xxx.com/api/Test/getEmployee/1 [Returns 500 Error]
2. https://111.11.111.11/api/Test/getEmployee/1 [Got Expected Result(404)]

[image]
[image]

Its working fine for the same API service and different params which is having data.

We have checked in code side, no error logged.

Sample Code :

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        try
        {                
                var employee = employeeManager.GetEmployee(employeeId);
                if (employee != null)
                {
                    return Ok(employee);
                }                              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Error occured in GetEmployee: " + ex);
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

We hosted the site in Azure server.

Is there any problem with the domain name hosting/ load balancer/ ARR server.

Please help us to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you suggesting that when you get the 500 error, its not hitting your service?  You might want to make sure that is truly the case with additional logging

Comment: @Nick I haven't added any suggestion on this scenario. Accessing through IP address Its return proper result, so I don't think this is Code error. But your thought, please.

Comment: without seeing the code, I can't agree or disagree, but the code could have conditional handling for the http headers and server variables that are provided - i.e. if(dns) handleDns() else  handleIp()  two separate code paths could yield different results for a similar request.  If you can provide some additional info such as some code snippets, and maybe some azure config.  This idea is just one of many many things that could be wrong- url rewrites, reverse proxy, load balancer (as you suggest)

Comment: @Nick I have added my sample controller method in the description. I haven't used any URL Rewrites for this method.

Comment: One thing i notice from your screen shots is the headers are different - count 4 vs count 6.  check those, make sure they are the same / as expected.  If still not working, post those values for us to look.

Comment: If you know enough about IIS site bindings, you should know that using domain name and IP address are completely different, and can be routed to completely different places. So the 500 might not even come from your ASP.NET code. To make full use of the error page, you should check headers and raw body (edit your question to include them).

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming Azure App Service** since you don't clearly state it and your tags are little confusing.

You are being terribly mislead by that 404. The 404 is returned by ARR, not by you API. That happens because you need a `Host: domain.com` with your request, you can't just HTTP/1.0 your way onto your site like in the Netscape days.

That public IP you're hitting is the entire App Service stamp (think thousands of tenants/apps), the `Host` header helps route the request to *your* API.

The bad news is your API returns a HTTP 500, but you can debug that, enable logging, disable custom errors via web.config (so you can see the stack trace) and turn on failed request tracing as well.

Comment: I have already tested this service within a hosted web server, Inside the server, I got expected output for both domain name and IP Address. And I have disabled the custom error in web config, but I did not get any stake trace.

Comment: Enable failed request tracing and check those.